# autocompletion with wildcards for cd in bash

Tags: bash, wildcards, autocomplete

Using bash on ubuntu (debian jessie/sid) I'm not sure why I can't do tab completion of a wildcard *with a builtin command*.

for example, suppose my current working directory contains the following subdirectories..

```
% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 userX 4096 2016-08-31 11:46:40 0830a/
drwxr-xr-x 2 userX 4096 2016-08-31 11:46:52 0830b/
drwxr-xr-x 2 userX 4096 2016-08-31 11:47:33 0831a/
drwxr-xr-x 2 userX 4096 2016-08-31 11:47:18 0831b/
drwxr-xr-x 2 userX 4096 2016-08-31 11:50:38 z0830z/
```

I am able to hit [tab] after typing 'ls -l *31a' and get the completion to occur..

```
ls -l *31a<tab>
```

completes to..

```
ls -l 0831a
```

however, if I attempt the same with the builtin 'cd' command, it will not complete..

```
cd *31a<tab>
```

.. will not complete

Also, using a trailing wildcard fails as well..

```
cd z*<tab>
```

.. will not complete

Interestingly, completion without a wildcard character works OK for the builtins. For example, I am able make this completion work OK:

```
cd z<tab>
```

is completed to..

```
cd z0830z/
```

furthermore, I can use the 'cd *31a' command as-is and have it succeed (so long as it is unique). But I want the expansion to occur so I know for sure what I'm cd-ing into.

My .inputrc contains this..

```
$if Bash
  Space: magic-space
  set mark-directories on
  set mark-symlinked-directories on
  set completion-ignore-case off
  set show-all-if-ambiguous on
$endif
```

I don't have a ~/.bash_completion file. I do have /etc/bash_completion, which only does a source of /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion. That latter file is a bit long so I won't include it here.

My ultimate goal is to be able to have wildcard completion work for the cd command.

Comment: This is a general problem with bash custom completion (we've had the same question [about patterns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351412/bash-custom-tab-completion-with-wildcards), unanswered so far). It works in zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fighting with the same problem. As @Gilles mentioned, there is no real bash-based solution right now.

Since `bash-completion` doesn't really add much functionality to `cd` (AFAIK only the use of `$CDPATH` directories), so if you're not using that then you can add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
compopt -o bashdefault cd
```

This will reset the behavior of the `cd` completion to default (where wildcard completion works), and will not change anything else.